# python writing only first line to the file

Tags: python, file-writing

My script is writing only the first line to the file. I checked the previous same questions, problem with them was writing to the file after the for loop so i tried both this:

```
import os
import sys
import pdb_atoms as atms
import numpy as np

path_to_ligands=('/home/user/Desktop/small_test/ligands/')
path_to_CMS=('/home/user/Desktop/small_test/CMS/')


with os.scandir(path_to_ligands) as lig:
    for each_file in lig:       
        text=open(each_file, "r")
        lines=text.readlines()
        CMS_coord= np.array( atms.CMS(each_file) )  #getting the coordinates of each atoms center of masses
        for line in lines:
            x =[]
            x.append( float(line[30:38]) - CMS_coord[0])
            x.append( float(line[38:46]) - CMS_coord[1])
            x.append( float(line[46:54]) - CMS_coord[2])
            line = line.strip()
            text_to_write=[line[:30] + ("%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f" % (x[0],x[1],x[2])) +line[54:]]
        new_name = path_to_CMS + each_file.name.replace('ligand', 'lig_CMS')
        with open(new_name, 'w') as w:
            for i in text_to_write:
                w.write(i + '\n')
```

and also this:

```
path_to_ligands=('/home/user/Desktop/small_test/ligands/')
path_to_CMS=('/home/user/Desktop/small_test/CMS/')


with os.scandir(path_to_ligands) as lig:
    for each_file in lig:       
        text=open(each_file, "r")
        lines=text.readlines()
        CMS_coord= np.array( atms.CMS(each_file) )  #getting the coordinates of each atoms center of masses
        for line in lines:
            x =[]
            x.append( float(line[30:38]) - CMS_coord[0])
            x.append( float(line[38:46]) - CMS_coord[1])
            x.append( float(line[46:54]) - CMS_coord[2])
            line = line.strip()
            text_to_write=[line[:30] + ("%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f" % (x[0],x[1],x[2])) +line[54:]]
            new_name = path_to_CMS + each_file.name.replace('ligand', 'lig_CMS')
            with open(new_name, 'w') as w:
                for i in text_to_write:
                    w.write(i + '\n')
```

in both ways it is writing only the first line. Output is this:

```
ATOM     36  C28 VFL L 288       2.449  -2.116   0.546  1.00 15.00      L    C
```

New at python, would appreciate some help :)

Comment: You're reopening the file each time through the loop, which empties the file first. Open it once before the loop.

Comment: Yes, because you are opening the file inside the loop.  Every time you open the file, it starts over.  So, open the file outside of the loop.

Comment: Why is `text_to_write` a list? It never has more than one element.

Comment: Note that actually it's the last line, not the first one that you see at the end :-)

Comment: Why aren't you using `with` to open `each_file`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are opening the file for each line, when you open the file with `w` the previous contents of the file are erased.

Open the file only once:

```py
import os
import sys
import pdb_atoms as atms
import numpy as np

path_to_ligands=('/home/user/Desktop/small_test/ligands/')
path_to_CMS=('/home/user/Desktop/small_test/CMS/')


with os.scandir(path_to_ligands) as lig:
    for each_file in lig:       
        new_name = path_to_CMS + each_file.name.replace('ligand', 'lig_CMS')
        with open(new_name, 'w') as w:
            text=open(each_file, "r")
            lines=text.readlines()
            CMS_coord= np.array( atms.CMS(each_file) )  #getting the coordinates of each atoms center of masses
            for line in lines:
                x =[]
                x.append( float(line[30:38]) - CMS_coord[0])
                x.append( float(line[38:46]) - CMS_coord[1])
                x.append( float(line[46:54]) - CMS_coord[2])
                line = line.strip()
                text_to_write=[line[:30] + ("%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f" % (x[0],x[1],x[2])) +line[54:]]
            for i in text_to_write:
                w.write(i + '\n')
```

Comment: Opening it in `a` mode means it will still have the contents from the previous runs of the script.

Comment: Correct! I updated my answer

Comment: You're using `new_name` before you assign it.

Comment: Use `with` to open `text` as well.

Comment: On this note, you can open both files in one line:  `with open(thing1, "r") as r, open(thing2, "w") as w: ...`

Comment: if i didnt open the text like this than i cant read the lines, i just tried @Barmar , i wrote the new_name line between the for each_file... and the with open(new_name)... lines, and it worked! @Matteo! Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: @TTT Of course you can: `with open(each_file, "r") as text:`

Comment: Hey, turns out i checked the wrong file as output, it didnt work guys, i still have the last line printed out. :(( @Barmar very true, i just tried it like that :)

Comment: It is working now, i will edit my post with the working version

Comment: @TTT You should put the solution in an answer, not the question.

Comment: @Barmar Right :D

Answer (score 0):

Working version:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import sys
import pdb_atoms as atms
import numpy as np

path_to_ligands=('/home/user/Desktop/small_test/ligands/')
path_to_CMS=('/home/user/Desktop/small_test/CMS/')


with os.scandir(path_to_ligands) as lig:
    for each_file in lig:       
        new_name = path_to_CMS + each_file.name.replace('ligand', 'lig_CMS')
        with open(new_name, 'w') as w:
            text=open(each_file, "r")
            lines=text.readlines()
            CMS_coord= np.array( atms.CMS(each_file) )  #getting the coordinates of each atoms center of masses
            for line in lines:
                x =[]
                x.append( float(line[30:38]) - CMS_coord[0])
                x.append( float(line[38:46]) - CMS_coord[1])
                x.append( float(line[46:54]) - CMS_coord[2])
                line = line.strip()
                text_to_write=line[:30] + ("%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f" % (x[0],x[1],x[2])) +line[54:]
                w.write(text_to_write + '\n')
```

Comment: This is just a code block offering no explanation on what was architecturally wrong in the original code. Please provide some insight so future readers can rapidly understand what was wrong. Understand that future readers might be stuck with similar issues but their code fragments will be absolutely unrelated to this, so your "working version" is specifically unacceptable as an answer.

Please provide an explanation and a minimalistic code snippet agnostic to all the numpy and pdb_atoms boilerplate that only obfuscate the nature of the issue.